# Create numerical restrictions for date; year, month and day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to put restrictions on a date input field so users don't put in exaggerating dates like the year 3000. I found this neat [solution](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2011/12/validate-date-using-jquery.html) which works. But I want the date in yyyy/mm/dd format with year also having restriction, so mm is between 1-12, dd is between 1-31, and yy is between 1900-2100.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DueqV/), I can't get it to work with format yyyy/mm/dd. If I change the dtArrays to

`dtMonth = dtArray[5];
    dtDay= dtArray[7];
    dtYear = dtArray[1];`

Year works but mm ends up being in place of dd. What could I be doing wrong? Also are there any better ways of accomplish this? Last question.. this problem seems to be pretty simple, what books on jquery/javascript would you recommend so I may be able to get this on my own?

Comment: Why 5 7 1? I assume you've still only got five capture groups, i.e. you want 3 5 1? (Do you need to capture the separators?) Can you show us the modified regex you've come up with to match yyyy/mm/dd?

Comment: I changed from this /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/; to /^(\d{4})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})$/;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what you get in `dtArray` (which isn't a great name). It's the output of the capture groups from this regex:

```
/^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/
```

which matches `mm/dd/yyyy` (where those are digits) so

- [1] = `m` or `mm`
- [2] = a `/` or `-` separator
- [3] = `d` or `dd`
- [4] = a `/` or `-` separator
- [5] = `yyyy`

They aren't offsets into the string. (`dtArray[0]` will be the whole date matched.) With your modified regex is

```
/^(\d{4})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})$/
```

i.e. four digits in the first position, then you'll get

- [1] = `yyyy`
- [2] = a `/` or `-` separator
- [3] = `m` or `mm`
- [4] = a `/` or `-` separator
- [5] = `d` or `dd`

and so

```
dtYear  = dtArray[1];
dtMonth = dtArray[3];
dtDay   = dtArray[5];
```

(Note at this point that the three variables will actually be strings, not integers, albeit containing string representations of integer values. However JavaScript being what it is, they'll be coerced into integers when you try and use them as integers.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Indeed I understood it wrong, I was thinking 1,3,5 were beginning of number of characters -.-